# SED commands for text transformations

Tags: linux, awk, docker, busybox, container

Kindly help. **RUNNING SUCCESSFUL IN LOCAL**
with help of awk achieved this below transformations,
**now locally** (Linux cent OS with GNU Awk 4.0.2 version) is running perfect, but problem is with the remote version:

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101016/discussion-on-question-by-abhi-nay-sed-commands-for-text-transformations).

Comment: Abhi Nay: once someone has answered a question (it had two upvotes within a day or two), it's inappropriate to substantively change the question, as it invalidates an existing answer. I will be rolling this question back to a version that pre-dates the posted answer and reopening it so that others may answer it. I will not lock it *yet*, so that it has a chance of being (re)voted on, but be aware that this post has been flagged three times because of the degree to which it has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

As long as it doesn't have to be `sed`, you can accomplish this using `GNU awk`. However, it will be lengthy because the substitution of the resource identifiers as in `sp.config.fal.proxyhost` can be necessary at more than one place while having to avoid transforming filenames, e.g. your `LiferayKeyStore.jks`.

Therefore, I propose an `awk` program consisting of two rules, one for those lines where a `${ ... }` must be transformed, and one for the case where only the key name at the beginning has to be transformed (actually, it is three rules: the first for the case of `${ ... }` found, the next for all cases where only a `key=value` statement was found, and one for "all other" cases including empty lines).

Assuming your input text is in a file called `config.cfg`, it would look as follows:

```
awk '/\$\{[[:print:]]*\}/ {match($0,"([[:print:]]+)=\\${([[:print:]]+)}([[:print:]]*)",a); gsub("\\.","_",a[1]); gsub("\\.","_",a[2]); print toupper(a[1])": (("toupper(a[2])"))"a[3]; next}; /[[:print:]]+=[[:print:]]+/ {match($0,"([[:print:]]+)=([[:print:]]+)",a); gsub("\\.","_",a[1]); print toupper(a[1])": "a[2]; next}; {print}' config.cfg
```

This does the following

- For all lines which contain the pattern `${...}`, use `match()` to localize the patterns "any number of printable characters up to an `=`", the pattern `${ ... }` with an enclosed string, and any following number of printable characters. All sections enclosed in round parentheses are marked as "sub-expressions", and their *actual* content is saved in the array `a`, with `a[1]` being the first sub-expression etc. We then use `gsub` on `a[1]`, the `key` part, and replace all periods with underscores. We do the same on the string enclosed in the `${...}` which is the second sub-expression `a[2]`. As output, we print the upper-case-converted version of the `a[1]` thus substituted, a `:`, and the upper-case-converted version of `a[2]` (but this time enclosed in `(( ... ))`. Last we print `a[3]` untransformed, which is simply "the remainder of the line". **Very important**: we use the `next` instruction to skip further processing of the line and restart with the next line, otherwise the line might be processed (and output) twice with different transformations.
- If we didn't stumble upon the `${ ... }`, but the line *does* contain a "key=value" statement (`/[[:print:]]+=[[:print:]]+/`, i.e. any non-zero number of printable characters, followed by a `=`, followed again by any non-zero number of printable characters), then apply the substitution and transformation only on the "key" part. Again, skip further processing if the rule matched.
- Finally, if none of the above rules fit, simply print the line "as is".

**Edit**

If there are situations in which you have empty values, i.e. `key=`, you will need to add another rule to catch that one, too:

```
awk '/\$\{[[:print:]]*\}/ {match($0,"([[:print:]]+)=\\${([[:print:]]+)}([[:print:]]*)",a); gsub("\\.","_",a[1]); gsub("\\.","_",a[2]); print toupper(a[1])": (("toupper(a[2])"))"a[3]; next}; /[[:print:]]+=[[:print:]]+/ {match($0,"([[:print:]]+)=([[:print:]]+)",a); gsub("\\.","_",a[1]); print toupper(a[1])": "a[2]; next}; /[[:print:]]+=[[:space:]]*/ {match($0,"([[:print:]]+)=([[:space:]]*)",a); gsub("\\.","_",a[1]); print toupper(a[1])":"; next}; {print}' config.cfg
```

It is not possible to absorb this third rule into the second one because you have `key=value` pairs which end in a `=` due to Base64 transformation.